# Is there a way to use SUMIF when you are searching date formatted cells? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have managed to create a formula, which searches for a date. However, I can only get it to work when the date column is formatted as Plain Text, unfortunately I can't format the sheet like that due to the way the timestamps are added. Is there a way to change my formula so I can avoid this issue?
`SUMIF($A$1:$A$16,"*"&text($E4,"dd/mm/yy")&"*",$B$1:$B$16)`
This is an example spreadsheet (which should hopefully be public).
Thanks in advance for any replys.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQyLQEaoLAHpf2UtE7ikFUFTYZ6D3jjYdOZlm-63ZjMdezC1cZn2h36zvYV9YoGMFHvbexIJR4cZoYd/pubhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to turn your timestamps into pure dates, (rather than date-times) with *math* rather than with *text manipulation*.  This is done a couple different ways, but the simplest in my opinion is the INT() function which just returns the integer portion of a decimal number.  Since dates are just numbers and time is a decimal value, this works well for stripping times off of date/timestamps.  Since you'll be applying the INT() to a whole columns worth of data, you need to use the ARRAYFORMULA() wrapper.

In your case:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(INT(A$1:A$16),E4,B$1:B$16))
```

Comment: Do you know any other ways? Although on this sheet there aren't any times involved they are involved on the original sheet and I have used them for other formula's so I couldn't remove them. That is unless I misunderstanding your reply and I could use int within the formula maybe?

Comment: @sophmp Yes, you misunderstood, i meant use INT in the formula as i wrote in the formula in my answer.

Comment: Yep thanks that work. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({INT(A:A), B:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]